# Going to Cyprus for Internship then to Italy for MS

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, italy, cyprus

I am an Indian, (still in India without a Schengen visa) will be going to Italy for my MS degree in September 2022. But prior to that, I want to go to Cyprus (Nicosia) for an internship (like from May to August) and then would like to go to Italy to start my master's. Did a bit of research and here are my questions:

1. Can I take a Schengen Visa through the Consulate of Italy (for the purpose of my MS) and then visit Cyprus for a few weeks and then continue my studies in Italy?
2. If I can, then can I stay for more than 90 days in Cyprus?
3. If you would be in my place what approach would you take to get to visit both of these countries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I take a Schengen Visa through the Consulate of Italy (for the purpose of my MS) and then visit Cyprus for a few weeks and then continue my studies in India?

The terminology is sometimes a bit confusing but the visa you will need for your studies in Italy isn't exactly a Schengen visa, it's a national visa. It also gives you the right to visit other countries in the Schengen area (and a few candidate countries) for up to 90 days. A visit to Cyprus *after* starting your studies may be possible but not a long(ish) internship.

Furthermore, even if a multiple-entry Schengen visa does exempt you from the requirement to get a visa for Cyprus, this visit to Cyprus must be incidental, it's not a valid reason to get a Schengen visa. The Italian consulate only issues visas when Italy is the main destination and you cannot expect it to grant you a visa just because you want to go to Cyprus.

The visa you will get from Italy will therefore be based on the documents you submit regarding your master's studies in Italy and is unlikely to start several months before the course begins. A visit *before* the beginning of the academic year on that basis will be impossible.

> If I can, then can I stay for more than 90 days in Cyprus?

No, it is not allowed to stay longer than 90 days in Cyprus on an Italian visa (of any kind). You can however visit Cyprus for up to 90 days with a long-stay visa or resident permit (which you would get for your studies). Do check whether you need some sort of work permit for the internship you have in mind. Even if you are allowed to visit Cyprus, you may not be allowed to complete a (paid) internship without additional permission.

> If you would be in my place what approach would you take to get to visit both of these countries?

It's a little tricky. The by-the-book approach is to apply for a Cyprus internship or work visa and as soon as you move there, apply for an Italian student visa from the local consulate. The problem with that is it will be difficult to get additional documents if needed, doesn't give you a lot of time and can get very costly if you don't get your visa.

I assume you have already secured your internship but if that's not the case, it might make sense to do the Cyprus internship at another time. Even if that's not possible, it might still be better to just give up on the internship to make sure you are able to join your master's programme in September.

Alternatively, if you have to go to Cyprus for less than 90 days, you could apply for a Cyprus short-stay visa (it's not a Schengen visa but it's similar). The problem you will face is that, unless you are able to get your Italian student visa well in advance, you may need to go back to India to submit your application and collect it from the Italian consulate there.

Comment: If I show this circumstance, will I be able to get a multiple entry Schengen Visa?

Comment: @SatyaPrakashDash What I was trying to say is that a Schengen (short-stay) visa is not relevant here. I am not sure what you mean with “this circumstance” (you alluded to several scenarios in your question) but I don't think a multiple-entry Schengen visa is what you should be seeking. I will add some details.

Comment: @SatyaPrakashDash a multiple entry Schengen visa is of no use to you because it's a short-stay visa that doesn't allow you to stay in Italy for longer than 90 days.  Since you're planning to go to Cyprus first, you should get a visa from Cyprus to permit you to go there for your internship and a separate visa from Italy to permit you to go there for your MS.  The visa you will get from Italy will almost certainly be valid from the beginning of your MS program in September 2022, in which case you will not be able to use it for anything in May or at any other time before the MS program starts.

Comment: @phoog can I apply for both countries' visas at the same time? as I won't have much time after my internship completion to do the visa process for Italy.

Comment: I was thinking the same. Is there any reason why the OP cannot do two separate applications in advance, one to Cyprus for the internship (work visa, whatever needed) and another to Italy for the studies?

Comment: @SatyaPrakashDash Yes, two visas is the way to go. If Italy is willing to entertain a visa 6+ months in advance then by any means do that: apply for both around the same time and leave for Cyprus with your Italian visa in the pocket. Problem could arise if the consulate wants to keep your passport or has rigid timelines for applications. Do insist and explain your situation but they might not care that it makes your trip impossible.